# unknown Exception while trying to upload image to parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload image file using this code:

```
if (mMediaUri != null ){
    Log.v("url = "+mMediaUri, "");

    //create parse object for image to upload
    final ParseObject imageUpload = new ParseObject("TestNotes");
    try {
        //convert image to bytes for upload.
        byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(getContext(), mMediaUri);
        if (fileBytes == null) {
            //there was an error
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There was an error. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);
            String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(getContext(), mMediaUri, "image");
            final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
            imageUpload.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        imageUpload.put("File", file);
                        sendNote.saveInBackground();
                        imageUpload.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success Uploading iMage!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        //there was an error
                        //there was an error
                        Log.v(""+e.getMessage(), " Error Here");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Our Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("our Error = "+ e1.getMessage(),"");

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e1.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

but its not working am getting `exception`  and ii tried ti figure out what the `exception` is but its not showing anything in my `logcat` or even in my `Toast`

am getting exception on this lines :

```
} catch (Exception e1) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Our Error",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.v("our Error = "+ e1.getMessage(),"");
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e1.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

i don't know why its showing me the only this Toast

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Our Error"
```

any idea what could be the Exception and why am not able to see it on my LogCat or in Toast ?? or what am doing wrong on my method ?? and the `mMdeiaUri` is the `Uri` of Image ,

thanks!  any guidance for making it right will be so helpful for me

on log calls am getting something like this :

```
01-27 00:51:43.799 2805-2805/pb.pocketboard I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
01-27 00:51:43.799 2805-2805/pb.pd W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 455: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-27 00:51:43.799 2805-2805/pb.pd D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-27 00:51:43.799 2805-2805/pb.pd I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
01-27 00:51:43.799 2805-2805/pb.pd W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 457: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-27 00:51:43.799 2805-2805/pb.pd D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
```

Comment: You won’t see anything in the verbose channel because you assigned all the message to the first argument. Try Log.v(“our Error”, e1.getMessage()) .

Comment: thanks for responding @mvai let me try this

Comment: @mvai please see my updated question am facing this Log.v problem fro a while , they are not printing anything even after  trying as you suggested

Comment: Sure you have changed it? Try commenting out that line and see if you get any toast.

Comment: its showing a Toast but without any text a blank Toast but it should show some thing on logcat cause i used `Log.v("our Error =  ", e1.getMessage());` even if   e1.getMessage() is null than at least it should show the "Our error" in logcat

Comment: It might be an empty exception that you are throwing inside the FileHelper methods. I would just debug and see where it breaks.

Comment: yeah but any idea why its not printing in logcat though ? or is my method for uploading image is not correct ?

Comment: Logs do not show (and instead throw some warnings) if there are too much characters in the first argument. That said, sometimes android studio logcat just freezes (to me at least) and won’t listen to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something wrong with the Uri fetching part. You can try this process to get image from your storage device and upload it to the parse cloud.

Say you have a button photoFromGallery to pick image...

```
photoFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1); // Here, 1 is for image file
        }
    });
```

Override onActivityResult to get done with the uploading process.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //requestCode = 1 for image file
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // Here you get the path of your image
        cursor.close();

        Bitmap bmpget = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100 (will be ignored for PNG type)
        bmpget.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream); 
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

        //Create a file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String filename = "img_"+timeStamp+".jpg";

        // Create the ParseFile
        ParseFile file = new ParseFile(filename,image);

        /**********************
         * Code for saving your file to the parseCloud either on a specific row or new row
         **********************/

    }

}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: well already i changed my approach because of time limitation  but yeah thanks a lot :) @Sudip